# mysql: Error Number: 1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to delete some data from 3 tables. Here is my SQL:

```
DELETE 
 FROM productdetail 
 JOIN (productdescription,productmineralcategories,productspeciescategories) 
 ON
   (
    productdetail.id = productspeciescategories.id_product 
    AND productdetail.id = productmineralcategories.id_product 
    AND productdetail.id = productdescription.id_product
    )    
  WHERE productdetail.id='".$data['id'].
```

And here is the output error:

Error Number: 1064

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'JOIN (productdescription, productmineralcategories,
>   productspeciescategories) ' at line 3

What does it mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Your DELETE statement should be:

```
$query="DELETE 
        FROM productdetail 
        WHERE productdetail.id='".$data[$id] . "'";
```

OR

```
$query="DELETE 
        FROM productdetail 
        WHERE productdetail.id='$data[$id]'";
```

OR do not add single quote if field type is numeric.

```
$query="DELETE 
        FROM productdetail 
        WHERE productdetail.id=$data[$id]";
```

Have a look at [DELETE JOIN syntax.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)